# Watir testing for equality

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

Working on a Cucumber/Watir test to test that a image rotator/cycle  is working.  My strategy is to the grab the active image in the rotator by css class  and dump that in to a variable. Then I click the next button and grab the active image (which should now be a new image) in the rotator by css class and dump it into a second variable.  Then I should be able to say img_rot_1 != img_rot_2  and have the test return true or false. This is the part were I am having trouble.

I am new to Ruby so I may be missing something simple.  Here is the test.

```
require 'step_definition/setup'

test_setup = Wsetup.new 'http://loginurl', 'uname', 'pass' # browser object created here as # test_setup.b
img_rot_1 = String.new
img_rot_2 = String.new 

When /^I click the next image button$/ do
  test_setup.do_login
  test_setup.b.goto('http://psu.dev1.fayze2.com/node/56')
  img_rot_1  = test_setup.b.li(:class => 'flex-active-slide').img.src
  test_setup.b.link(:class => 'flex-next').click
end

Then /^the rotator should move to the next image$/ do
  img_rot_2  = test_setup.b.li(:class => 'flex-active-slide').img.src
  img_rot_1 != img_rot_2
end
```

img_rot_1 != img_rot_2   and img_rot_1 == img_rot_2   both pass  -  so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use instance variables if you want to access variable that is created in one step from another step.

Something like:

```
When /^I click the next image button$/ do
  # more code here
  @img_rot_1  = test_setup.b.li(:class => 'flex-active-slide').img.src
end

Then /^the rotator should move to the next image$/ do
  img_rot_2  = test_setup.b.li(:class => 'flex-active-slide').img.src
  @img_rot_1.should_not == img_rot_2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `Then` step to fail, it needs an assertion that fails, not just a statement that evaluates to false.

Assuming you are using the RSpec expectations, you would want something like:

```
img_rot_1.should_not eq(img_rot_2)
```